# How can I build a vite application and host it on my website, but not in root of website?

Tags: vite

I have a webserver running. I've made an application with vite (react) and I would like to host this application at a subdirectory of my website. E.g.

`mydomain.com/myapps/myviteapp`

My webserver is Apache Tomcat and usually when I have a static site I can just put in the directory I want to find it in. e.g. For this I would put it in

`/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/myapps/myviteapp`

The problem with this is that vite build probably assumes that my site is hosted at root, because urls to assets are like this:

```html
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.27ec30df.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.6d428de0.css">
```

So naturally that wont work, because the file `index.27ec30df.js` isn't really at `/assets/index.27ec30df.js`. It is at `/myapps/myviteapp/assets/index.27ec30df.js`...

How can I build a static website with vite, and put it in any "subdirectory" of my webserver?

Answer (score 3):

Configure Vite's [`base`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#base) (the base URL) to be the intended subdirectory path:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: '/myapps/myviteapp/',
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-base-url-2?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: Upvoted because this is probably the way. But this means is I have to (re)configure this if I decide to move the application to a different subdirectory. Does the project really have to be "self-aware" like this? Can it be built to work from any directory?

Comment: In that case, use `''` or `'./'` as the base URL, but your mileage may vary with Vite 2. Vite 3 is supposed to address this ([`vitejs/vite#7644`](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/7644)) -- released in `vite@3.0.0-alpha.1`.

Comment: Or add a command line flag.  This is straight from the vite docs:

If you are deploying your project under a nested public path, simply specify the base config option and all asset paths will be rewritten accordingly. This option can also be specified as a command line flag, e.g. vite build --base=/my/public/path/